# Any possibility to expand the view of the page itself?

Tags: feature-request, design

I am struggling a bit when I want to see some code, some users have "long" code (let's say 150 characters in a line), so the default view is not enough and I have a 2k ultra wide screen (3440 x 1440).

So I have a lot of space, I can have 3 PHPStorm tabs and I will see all code if it sticks to 120 characters per line, so I will share with you what I see and how I would like to see it (at least for 2k screens or bigger than 1080). Also have in mind that I have hidden the menu to see a little more...

[image]

[image]

Now, how would I like to see it ?

#### This is one possibility

[image]

See that removing the sidebar (at least inside a question) already gets 90% better... I do not use the sidebar inside questions (I always open questions in new tabs, because I could lose my filters/pagination).

#### This is other possibility (also have in mind we could have or not the sidebar, I will share only one screenshot)

[image]

I just changed the `max-width` to `2000px` and that's it ! Already way better view for bigger screens...

---

This `2000px` width is just an example... We need wider pages specially for code, specially most people is new and don't post code correctly formatted... It should be a "check in" option as some people don't like it...

Comment: *"Already way better view for bigger screens..."* - I wholeheartedly disagree, those lines are too long the the point of being unwieldy and difficult to read

Comment: I'm using the Answer by [double-beep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10607772/double-beep) to [Hide the Stack Exchange sidebar](https://stackapps.com/questions/6652/hide-the-stack-exchange-sidebar/8673#8673) to toggle the sidebar away when I want to :)

Comment: @Nick Maybe I going from `1100px` to `2000px` is too much, I also see that, but the default is way too smaller for some code... I am getting crazy reading people's code in a small part of the screen, also I have to take into account that most users do not know how to post clean code, that makes the thing even more difficult... This is also why it should be an option and not a must... I would love it and surely more people too.

Comment: @Scratte Thank you for sharing that script ! I would prefer to have something _native_ like hidding the left menu by default, rather than a script/plugin, if I switch browser I lose this ability unless I download that again... I want the page to have this sort of features, would be awesome !

Comment: The left menu bar can be hidden by a setting in your preferences on your account. I assume you meant the right menu bar :) As far as I understand the fixed size of 1100px to the window is [status-by-design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues/361378#comment1207410_361378)

Comment: I currently have the `hide left menu` option on, so I can see a little more. But I am talking about the right menu bar, called `sidebar`...

Comment: Why not set up three Stack Overflow screens side by side if you have that much screen space?

Comment: @HereticMonkey because I work with one at a time... When I have 3 PHPStorm tabs is because I have backend code, frontend code/some documentation and the live view...

Comment: Browsers have found a way - the flex display type is designed exactly to be able to rather easily support this kind of configurable scenario where one column does not have to take up a static amount of space. So yeah, I'll go along with you that this can be implemented in a configurable way. However doing so in a pre-existing mature website (or rather: several dozen websites)... probably far harder to achieve in practice. Scratte's link alludes as much.

Comment: @Gimby I agree with you and totally understand because I am a web developer too, so I understand the impact it could have, but also we have to understand that this website is old, and we came from 720p to 4k... I am not requesting a 4k size, but a little bit bigger... being able to hide the side bar (right side bar) is already super good... why can't we have that in place like we do for the left menu ? Imagine social medias, and big important companies saying "we will not change that because it can have an impact"... they do the stuff they need to do without user plugins... just that.

Comment: When answering questions, I use [my userscript](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/tree/master/Three-Columns) so that the question, answer textarea, and answer preview can all be seen on a single screen. I find it invaluable. [Screenshot](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/master/Three-Columns/userscript-screenshot.png)